# How valid is saying "improve x while not decreasing y" in business metric optimization?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, optimization

Suppose you are an advertisement business, and you have two revenue streams `x` and `y`. Let's say the value of `x` and `y` is not trivially comparable - maybe they have different growth potentials. In any case though, the more the better.

Now, suppose I have two algorithms `A` and `B`, and thanks to an online A/B test I know `A` yields `(x=10±1, y=10±1)`, while `B` yields `(x=15±1, y=10±1)`. Clearly, I should accept `B` as it gives me better results.

The problem is, what if I get `A -> (x=10±1, y=10±1)` and `B -> (x=15±1, y=8±1)`? Surprisingly many (almost everyone) at my company claims I should "improve one, while not harming the other". But this doesn't make sense to me for two reasons:

1. I introduce an arbitrary line - I essentially declare that reducing `x` or `y` by however little has infinitely large negative impact, and no amount of improvement in the other KPI can compensate for it. But those values are arbitrary - if I happened to get `A -> (x=10±1, y=11±1)` for whatever reason, I would have insisted on at least getting `y=11±1` instead of being content with `y=10±1`, which would be irrational.
2. I can "sneak in" the same change if I split it in steps. Since I can't measure the result with arbitrary precision, I have to declare some Minimum Detectable Effect. I.e. at most I can say "improve one KPI while not reducing the other by more than z%". If I had an algorithm improvement that reduces `y` by more than `z%` I couldn't ship it, but if I hack that same change into multiple pieces, such that each step only degrades `y` by less than `z%`, eventually I can ship the same change!

To me it just sound illogical to say "improve x while not harming y", but I hear it so often from so many people - people that have data science background as well - that I'm thinking maybe I'm missing something here.

For me, it will make a lot more sense to estimate the relationship between `x` and `y` somehow (e.g. by saying `2 * x is roughly equal to 1 * y`), and say "let's improve `x + 2 * y`".

Comment: If you can assign values to `x` and `y` that are explicit and on the same scale--e.g., dollars--then you can solve this algebraically and show how a scenario in which one stream suffers might still be optimal. But I suspect cultural aspects will still make that a tough sell...